# Designing a common database for multiple, unique apps

Tags: database

I'm new to the world of databases so apologies in advance if I am not using the proper vocabulary.

I'm looking into the design considerations for a cloud-hosted app store for both online and offline use. Certain apps will rely on the same information, like personnel info.

1. Is it better to first create the database with all the common information and then have the apps use this common database?
2. If there are unique fields that one app needs but the other doesn't, is there a way to download only the needed fields (to save memory and data plan usage)?
3. Suppose certain, but not most, apps require near-instantenous speed of access, then should they have their separate, unique database with the same information?

I'll also appreciate any suggestions for further reading on the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a clear understanding what is common and will remain common, it's a good idea to design it first. But knowing it precisely from the start is hard, so be conservative.
2. Databases are not about downloading, but (mostly) about querying and updating. You can of course only query the rows and fields you need, and only transfer them.
3. Having separate databases may improve speed. But a correct design that makes queries efficient is usually more important. Also, you always have a conflict between pre-loading and speed of access with regard to bandwidth, and between caching / replication and speed of  access with regard to memory consumption.

For us to better answer you questions, please explain what problem are you [*really*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) solving. Doing that, and also doing some background reading on databases, will help you *ask* your question better.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I don't know what problem I am really solving, unfortunately. Right now there is a bit of chaos in the organization that there are thousands of unique or redundant applications/software programs that are just as diverse in nature as your Google app store. Higher ups have said that they want  to migrate them all to cloud. Without getting a look at all these programs, I'm first trying to develop higher level guidance on what might be the best general (but not the only available) approach.

Comment: I'd concentrate on finding out and formulating the correct problem, and vetting my understanding with the right stakeholders. Before that, I'd try to not write a single line of code for that project. One thing worse than sitting in inaction is to sink time and money on solving a wrong or non-existent problem.